# jquery event are not works on ajax loaded content(html)

Tags: javascript, jquery

When i load html content by using ajax, the jquery events on loaded html is not work.

For Example-

I have a jquery function-

```
$('.test').on('click', function(){
  alert('hi');
});
```

ajax response :

```
<div>
  <p class="text">test data</p>
</div>
```

Now clicking on ajax loaded data is not firing jquery On click event as i defined.

Comment: `'test' !== 'text'`?

Comment: The event handler is only bound to elements that existed in the document at the time `$('.test').on('click', function(){` gets executed. Go read up on _event delegation_ for an easy way to deal with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please try it, hope it helps

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
   $.get(url, {}, function(response) {
     $('#ajax-loadedData').html(response); 
     bindEventOnLoadedData();
  });
}); 

function bindEventOnLoadedData() {
   $('.test').on('click', function(){
    alert('hi');
   });
}
```